# How do you copy a single word from an SMS?

Tags: ios, sms

I have received an SMS with an unlock PIN for an app. I now want to copy & paste that code into the app.

When I press on the message, I only get the option to copy the whole message. How can I only copy the PIN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, you can't select a single word from a received SMS.

You're going to have to copy the whole SMS to a note (Or to the "reply" input), then select the part you want from that note.

That said, if the sent code is numeric, a user *can* directly copy it.
iOS will interpret it as a possible phone number, and allow several options when the number is touched & held down.

Comment: Oh, cool. Thanks for that additional information :)